# Android Seller Refunds and Cancelations - Can users still upgrade their apps?

Tags: android, google-play, marketplace

I want to refund a customer's money without restricting their use of the app. Basically I want to give the app to some people for free by refunding their money.

Prior to funds being transfered I can "Cancel entire order."

After funds have been transfered I can "Refund Some Money."

In either, or both, of these scenarios does the customer retain ownership of the app so they can still receive all future updates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have never been able to find anything definitively declaring how these operations work, but I can tell you this from experience refunding purchases that it will not do what you're looking for. "Refund Some Money" is misleading because a full refund is the only kind of refund that CheckOut will let you do on an Android purchase, and it will cause the program to be removed from the user's handset.

It'd sure be nice if Google would give us a way to distribute the occasional complementary or promotional purchase through the Market, but that's not how it works at present.